# querySelectorAll returns NodeList with undefined objects

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning javascript/html5 and im stuck with a frustrating problem:
my code was supposed to make 2 elements clickable but it does nothing at all. debugger gives me no info (using chrome). I tried using document.write to debug and it seems to return an empty NodeList.

```
<!doctype=html>
<html lang = "en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><script type="text/javascript">
function getStuff(){
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(".tuna");
    for(var i=0; i<list.lenght; i++){
    list[i].onclick = talk; 
    }
}
function talk(){
    alert("this could be a fish");
}
window.onload=getStuff();
</script></head>
<body>
<p class="tuna">bla</p>
<p class="bacon">bla2</p>
<p class="tuna">bla3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel retarded for asking such a simple question but i studied the problem for far 2 long and i hope someone can easily find an answer in minutes.

Comment: First problem I found: `window.onload=getStuff;` Second: `.length`

Comment: @chris it was the .length that got me,i tried to add paranthesis in desperation to see if it helped. Tyvm i literaly checked the code 50 times and didnt spot the error.

Comment: I only spotted it when I put a `console.log(list[i])` inside the loop and got nothing :)